# Standard user in Win7 can't reconnect to network drive after logging off

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking

I have a user on Win7 Enterprise with a mapped network drive.  It uses credentials for a user account on a different machine.  At fresh start up, I can log into Windows, open the network drive, and everything looks great.  However, if I log out with that user and log back in, trying to access the network drive returns an "Access is Denied" message.  The networked drive is set to reconnect at logon.

I've tried a number of fixes including:

- disabling UAC
- setting net use persistence to "yes" and "no"
- setting "Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/System/Logon" policy "Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon" to "Enabled"

Through all of this, short of "net use /delete" or a restart, nothing seems to work.

Comment: Move your answer into the answer section below

Comment: If that answer worked for you @Ross can you please give me some green  if possible?

Answer (score 0):

-**delete** your map drive,

-remove ALL other mapped drives if possible

-now **disconnect** from the network by either disabling the adapter or pulling the lan cable to the nearest switch/hub/router/back of mobo,

-**reboot twice**, preferably once in **safe mode with networking**, then reboot right after back to normal

-now **recreate mapped drive**, but when you recreate it, make sure you check the **use different credentials**,

-put in your normal credentials

-make sure they are remembered, i.e. reconnect each time

-give it **2-3 minutes** for network for properly establish, there's so many protocols and packets doing crazy things, then there's more waiting for idle..
then access some files on that network one last time,

-then **reboot**

-double click on computer

-wait **5 minutes** after reboot

-now see if this network is re-established on its own

-now rebuild your other maps, and hope they don't break things.